# Onclick function in the <script> tag instead of the <button> not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use the onClick() function inside the script tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        const btn = document.getElementById("mainButton");
        btn.onclick = function(){
            alert("You shouldn't have clicked this button!");
        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="mainButton">Do not click this button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I looked on the internet to find the syntax to do this it looked something like the above.

However when I run this script it doesn't work and I have no clue why and Any other way I've tried becomes a syntax error.

Comment: change `<script>` to `<script defer>` and try again - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use defer or move the script tag to the end of the body.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
         const btn = document.getElementById("mainButton");
        btn.onclick = function(){
            alert("You shouldn't have clicked this button!");
        };
        });
       
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="mainButton">Do not click this button</button>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="mainButton">Do not click this button</button>
         <script>
        const btn = document.getElementById("mainButton");
        btn.onclick = function(){
            alert("You shouldn't have clicked this button!");
        };
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a [_very_ commonly asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/14028959?lq=1). Please don't answer those as per [answer]. Instead, flag them to be closed as [a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates).

Comment: Thanks, it works! I somehow forgot that you would have to write the script after the tag has been declared, otherwise it wouldn't exist at the time of execution.